# Writing a batch file for running multiple commands within an .exe

Tags: batch-file, cmd, exe

I have a file (xyz.gcode) to be inputted to a command line host software (pronsole.exe) for 3d printing.
The process is as follows:

1. Launch pronsole.exe using "pronsole" command
2. connect to 3d printer using "connect" command
3. load xyz.gcode using "load" command

(connect and load are commands within the .exe)
I have written the following script as of now.

```
@echo OFF
rem Open pronsole. Connect. Load.
pronsole 
connect
load xyz.gcode
PAUSE
```

The execution of the batch file stops when the .exe is launched (i.e after the pronsole command). So the connect and load commands are not executed. Any way to overcome this ?

Comment: Read the program documentation to see if it accepts command line parameters. Does it? If not, you're probably out of luck. You're expecting us to know how some third-party command line program accepts input, and you'll need to check the documentation or ask the vendor about that part first.

Comment: you need something like `echo connect|proconsole` , but without knowing more I dont know how to proceed with multiple command.may be `fileWithCommands>proconsole` will work? or `type fileWithCommands|proconsole` ?

Comment: @Ken  Hmm. It doesn't accept command line parameters. Will look at alternative ways. Thanx !

Comment: as the most desperate ideq you can take a look at this [sendKeys.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/sendKeys.bat)  though you'll need to see what is the title of the console.

Comment: Remove or comment out `@echo off` in order to see what is really happening. Is `proconsole` a .exe program?

Comment: @lit Sorry for the late comment. Yes pronsole is a .exe program

Comment: @npocmaka Thanks ! That could work.